# base 64 decode and get data out of it

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I know its not the best way to save data but the database is given to me and I can't change it anymore but i need to get data out of the column overigedata which is base64 serialized. So far i came up with this but its not working like this.

```
$result20 = $dbhandle->query("SELECT base64_decode(overigedata) FROM email WHERE 'date' BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND  DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) ");
$row_cnt20 = $result20->num_rows;
```

The output decoded of one of the rows is:

```
a:3:{s:15:"HTTP_USER_AGENT";s:108:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87
Safari/537.36";s:11:"REMOTE_ADDR";s:11:"80.00.00.00";s:4:"DATE";
s:19:"25-04-2016 15:09:35";}
```

I would like decode it and count the rows where the date is today/one day.

Comment: Use [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) function

Comment: Thanks im gonna take a look into it how to use it thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Data stores as serialize format.

```
 $var ='a:3:{s:15:"HTTP_USER_AGENT";s:108:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.87
Safari/537.36";s:11:"REMOTE_ADDR";s:11:"80.00.00.00";s:4:"DATE";
s:19:"25-04-2016 15:09:35";}';

$data = unserialize($var);
```

It will return data as an array() format.
It seems to me there is some issue in your data. It was not serialize properly.